# Repository as only communication with Data Layer?

Tags: android, repository, clean-architecture

I am following clean architecture, and I understand the use of the repository for actions like getUsers or queryUsers. However does not make sense to me the use of a repository to login a user. How should I communicate with the Data Layer then, should I skip the repository layer and access the network layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I definitely think that you should not skip layers.

The whole point of introducing a certain architecture is to follow it without exception, so all your app modules behave in an expected and predictable way.

So, if you look at it from a different angle, what does logging in mean? You get a username and a password and you must check if they match a username and a password that are stored in your datasource. To do this, you run a query against your current users. And queries are run where - in the repository! You said it yourself - the repository is where all querying should happen. What is implementation behind it is of no importance.

So, my suggestion is to add a method like this one:

```
public interface UserRepository {

    User findByUsernameAndPassword(@NonNull String username, @NonNull String 
password);

}
```

If you manage to find a user - good, he's authenticated, if not - sorry, try again.

Answer (score 0):

from [this guid](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) i think using repository is a better choice. my answer based on the definition of the repository quoting :

> Repository modules are responsible for handling data operations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in clean architecture you should not skip layers. I see a few options here:

- `userRepository.get\set-User()` - for me, it looks a bit weird because Repository is an abstraction over collection while we need only one.
- create an abstraction over user storage. For example, `userStorage.get\set-User() or userStorage.login(User), logout(), get()`